# Input type text for dates

Tags: html, input

is there a way to use an input type text for dates ? What I mean is just to limit the the input text at

> YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate HTML5 date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151965/how-to-validate-html5-date-format)

Comment: If it is OK to open a calendar or you're happy using dd-mm-yyyy  format instead of yyyy-mm-dd as date you could use this in the html: <input id="date" type="date">

Answer (score 0):

Need to set type of field.

`<input type="date">` is what you need.

For more about types, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp